# how to query EKS version in datadog?

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks, datadog

I am trying to make a simple dashboard in Datadog to display the current kubernetes versions of EKS clusters in di

fferent environments. How
ever, a

s far as I

can tell this is not someth

ing that is queryable. It appears based on https://docs.datadoghq.com/ag
ent/kubernetes/data
_collected/ that
this is not a metric t
hat is collec
ted, but I find it hard to believe that there is no way to do

this

.

***EDITED TO REFORMAT***

Comment: Please reformat the text in your question.

Comment: @AbhishekDutt wow cheers for the insight mate, problem solved!